# Which Statistical Test to predict DV using paired data and several IVs?

Tags: multiple-regression, t-test, predictive-models, paired-data

What I have is a hiring analysis where we have a Dependent Variable for pre test and post test for a paired sample (same location's hiring success measure before and after treatment). I also have a host of other characteristics such as the location's region, the type of business, etc. What I aim to do is determine the best way to predict how successful hiring will be for a given region/business type etc. In my head, basically multiple regression, except that I have paired results as well. What would be the best approach to this? I typically lean on Excel/R Statistics.

Example of data

Location   IV  - Montana

Business_Type  IV - Sales

PreSuccess  DV  - 46%

PostSuccess DV  -  88%

Thanks for your time folks!

Comment: Have you considered logistic regression? Logistic regression outputs a probability of success in a binary outcome (0 = no hire, 1 = hire)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple regression can work on each dependent variable, so you would have to do 2 regressions: 1 for pre-success and 1 for post-success. If you are interested in the question "can these (indepedent) variables (e.g. location, business type, etc.) predict a *change* in the success rate?", you will need to do another regression. First, create a new variable Y=post-pre. This operation must be pairwise. Positive values of Y indicate increased performance, whereas negative values indicate decreased performance. Then, run the multiple regression on Y.